# Using system as actor in use case diagram

Tags: uml, diagram, use-case

I am developing a timetable app for the college. System needs to notify the users about class before 15 minutes and should turn mobile to silent mode during the classes automatically. How can I represent these requirements in use case diagram. Can I make system an actor to show system triggers the alarm and turns mobile to silent mode?

Comment: absolutely yes, actor does not necessary have to be a "human being"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same idea as [Vladimir's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26832855/3566846). This is how I would draw..

[image]

Comment: Hi,I am afraid, the system will not interact with user during execution of "Triggers the alarm and turns mobile to silent mod" if User actor is not connected to this usecase. UseCase says that system executes usecase with interaction (collaboration) with actors connected to usecase. Consequently, User will not be notified to do needed operation.

Answer (score 1):

If your timetable application should notify users, than you must define usecase of this application for example "Notification" with two actors. Actor "User" notified by app, and actor time defined as "15 minutes before class". Time actor initializes UseCase as well. See UML superstructure UseCases/Actor section.

Comment: Actors are always external to your system, so never the system itself. Time as an actor is an accepted practice.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Can we consider time as an actor?

Comment: @user3856376 Yes, I've seen Time, Clock, Scheduling System as actors in these kind of circumstances.